# What would be Url for nested resource route?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am able to display all comments of a post using the below code

```
public function index($post_id)
{

    $comments = post::find($post_id)->comments;        
    return view ('comment.index', compact ('posts','comments'));
}
```

and in view index.blade.php

```
<p> This is comment title {{ $comment->title }}</p>
<p> This is comment name {{ $comment->name }}</p>
```

but cannot go to the url of each comments ie. show.blade.php gets error with below code when add a "href="

```
<a href="{{ url('posts/' . $post->id . '/comment '/' . $comment->id . ')}}" >{{ $comment->name }}</a> 
<p> This is comment title {{ $comment->title }}</p>
 <p> This is comment name {{ $comment->name }}</p>
```

what will be the url to visit and show posts/1/comments/1 currently I am getting error undefined  $post .

Comment: The route should be defined in your routes file. Since Laravel 5.3, the file is named 'web.php' and 'api.php' in the routes directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sending a variable named `post` to the blade. And looking at the follow piece of code

```
return view ('comment.index', compact ('posts','comments'));
```

`posts` also looks undefined.

You need to send the post to the view instead of just the comments.

In the controller change:

```
$comments = post::find($post_id)->comments;        
return view ('comment.index', compact ('posts','comments'));
```

To

```
$post = post::find($post_id);        
return view ('comment.index', compact ('post'));
```

And then in your view change

```
<a href="{{ url('posts/' . $post->id . '/comment '/' . $comment->id . ')}}" >{{ $comment->name }}</a> 
<p> This is comment title {{ $comment->title }}</p>
<p> This is comment name {{ $comment->name }}</p>
```

To

```
{foreach $post->comments as $comment}
    <a href="{{ url('posts/' . $post->id . '/comment '/' . $comment->id . ')}}">{{ $comment->name }}</a> 
    <p> This is comment title {{ $comment->title }}</p>
    <p> This is comment name {{ $comment->name }}</p>
{/foreach}
```

I would also suggest using the `route()` function instead of `url()`. You can find more about that [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-route)

Comment: Thank you @Amando but getting error "A non-numeric value encountered " also the error "Undefined variable: comment" if the href url is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you're not passing post ID to the view. Do this instead:

```
return view ('comment.index', compact ('post_id', 'comments'));
```

Then use the variable in the view, for example:

```
{{ url('posts/' . $post_id . '/comment '/' . $comments->first()->id . ')}}
```